# Set limit and offset in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, limit

I'm working with PostgreSQL database and there are 20 records in my table. I wish to retrieve the set of every 5 records sequentially from database. Actually I have tried following query and it's working fine to retrieve first 5 records.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM public.testlogin limit 5
```

But now I wish to retrieve next 5 records from same database without making any change in my table structure while retrieving. I have tried the offset also and thats working too but for that I have to make changes in query each time.

How should i do to this without making changes in table contents in comparison to the previous five records fetched? I wish to make changes in query so it displays next 5 records on each hit.

Comment: Without making any change in your query? That's a weird requirement indeed, what's the logic behind?

Comment: there are lots of techniques involved for pagenation of records. you can find good ones over internet.

Comment: thanks foe reply .where should i??any site suggestion pls..

Comment: Why not pass the values for limit and offset as parameters to your query? Then you don't need to change the query itself, just the way you call it.

Answer (score 0):

I fear for that purpose you need to make use of a high level programming language where you can mix programming-logic with SQL.

Java for example is easy to learn and has the Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) implementation.

Comment: If he's not willing to change his SQL code to add `offset`, I don't think he'll want to migrate the whole project to Java and learn the language meanwhile.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario It's often a good idea to step ahead and learn new (and better) ways of doing things. Maybe it will encourage him to improve ... at least I hope so :-)

Answer (score -1):

Well, you are talking to the database in a language called `SQL`.

How would you tell the database which "next 5 records" you want to retrieve without actually... telling the database which records you want (by specifying them in the SQL query)!?